# How to create Nx 15 workspace with Karma/Jasmine instead of Jest/Cypress

Tags: nrwl-nx

Using `create-nx-workspace --preset=angular-monorepo …` (or some similar Angular preset), how can I opt for Karma/Jasmine instead of Jest/Cypress (using create-nx-workspace 15.x)? Is that possible at workspace level?

(I have seen https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1572 which answers the question at the module level, but `create-nx-workspace --unit-test-runner=…` seems to have no effect.)

Comment: In the end it took me little effort to just migrate from Jasmine to Jest; syntax and keywords were mostly the same (no rewrite of tests necessary), in other cases there was a very close counterpart (simple find&replace keywords was often sufficient). So abandoning Karma/Jasmine for the Nx default test framework/runner was quite easy and painless. (And now I don't need a headless browser anymore, which simplifies test setup even more.)